# Django form instance not showing default value when using angularJs

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

**In views.py**

```
def demo(request,EID):
  instance = Employee.objects.get(EID=EID)
  form = Update(instance=instance)
  return render(request, 'files/demo.html', {'form': form, })
```

**In Forms.py**

```
class Update(forms.ModelForm):
    Name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=75,
                                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'ng-model': 'Name', 'required': 'true'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Employess
        fields = ('Name',)
```

**In Html :**

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="id_Name" maxlength="75" name="Name" ng-model="Name" required="true" type="text" value="Amit">
```

But problem is that when the value of input "Amit" is not showing in Design.It shows Blank value and when I get value from Console through JavaScript that also return Blank value.SO how can i show this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `ng-model` you can not set default like this. You need to use `ng-init`. You can do something like this:

```
// HTML
<div ng-init=init({{ dict_from_django_view }})>
    // your form here
</div>

// in angular controller
$scope.init = function(data){
     // set form defaults here
}
```